# Apps Script genera entradas duplicadas en Google Calendar

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms, google-calendar

Buen día, tengo un formulario donde los docentes registran sus inasistencias y que se cargan a un Calendario de Google, hasta ahora funcionaba todo bien, pero hace unos días comenzó a duplicar e incluso triplicar las entradas al calendario.
Las respuestas no están duplicadas, sólo en el calendario.
Cuando se guarda el formulario guarda la palabra "Confirmado" que es sustituida por "Agendado" una vez que se carga al calendario. Agradezco si alguien me puede ayudar.
El código es el siguiente:

```
//para que se actualice automáticamente al recibir
//una nueva inasistencia
function CrearTriggerFormulario()
{
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   ScriptApp.newTrigger("crearAgenda")
     .forSpreadsheet(sheet)
     .onFormSubmit()
     .create();
}

//función que crea la nota en el Calendario
function crearAgenda(){
  //obtengo el calendario
  var calInasistencias = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('idDelCalendario');
  Logger.log('Calendario: ' + calInasistencias.getName());

//Obtengo la hoja
//  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  spreadsheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Agenda");
  Logger.log('Hoja' + spreadsheet.getName());
    
  //var datos = spreadsheet.getRange("A2:B500").getValues();
  var datos = spreadsheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (x=1; x<datos.length; x++){
    var nombre = datos[x][0]; //Logger.log('nombre: ' + nombre);
    var fechaIni = new Date(datos[x][1]); //Logger.log('fechaIni: ' +fechaIni);
    var fechaFin = new Date(datos[x][2]); //Logger.log('fechaFin: ' +fechaFin);
    var materias = datos[x][3]; //Logger.log('Materias: ' +materias);
    var grupos = datos[x][4]; //Logger.log('Grupos: ' +grupos);
    var estado = datos[x][5];//Logger.log('Estado: ' +estado);
    if (estado=='Confirmado') {  //El formulario por defecto se crea con 'Confirmado'

      if(fechaIni.getDay()==fechaFin.getDay() && fechaIni.getMonth()==fechaFin.getMonth() && fechaIni.getFullYear()==fechaFin.getFullYear()){ //(fechaIni==fechaFin){
        
        calInasistencias.createAllDayEvent(nombre + ' ' + materias + ' ' + grupos, fechaIni); 
        spreadsheet.getRange(x+1,6).setValue('Agendado');  //Para que no repita la agenda
      }
      else{
        calInasistencias.createEvent(nombre + ' ' + materias + ' ' + grupos, fechaIni, fechaFin);
        spreadsheet.getRange(x+1,6).setValue('Agendado');  //Para que no repita la agenda
      }
      }
}
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el sentido del `for` en este código? ¿No será eso lo que está creando entradas duplicadas, triplicadas, etc? ¿Acaso no es más simple crear la entrada de calendario escuchando los cambios o nuevas entradas en el formulario? Revisa para más detalles [*Installable Triggers*](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable?hl=en).

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, le quité el for, le asigné a x el valor de datos.length-1 e igual repite las entradas.

Comment: ¿No será que el trigger se está disparando varias veces por algún motivo? [Revisa aquí](https://script.google.com/home/triggers) tus activadores, y, a la derecha, en los tres puntitos del activador del formulario revisa sus ejecuciones. Y, revisa que no tienes activadores duplicados para ese formulario, etc. Debes estar logueada con tu cuenta de Google para ver la información.

Comment: Exacto, era eso, tenía en este momento 5 activadores, eliminé 4 y ahora funciona correctamente, muchas gracias!! Lo que no sé es por qué tenía tantos activadores generados.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando recibes entradas duplicadas suele ser por dos motivos:

1. Algún bucle o secuencia o valor mal puesto en el código
2. Algún activador que se está disparando varias veces

Siendo que has revisado el código y confirmas que todo está correcto a ese nivel, entonces revisa los activadores.

[Desde este enlace](https://script.google.com/home/triggers), una vez logueada en Google, podrás ver todos los activadores de tus diferentes proyectos, revisa que los de ese formulario u hoja ligada a él no estén duplicados.

Otra forma de ver los activadores es abriendo el proyecto, y seleccionando la opción `Activadores` en el panel de la izquierda:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Haciendo click en esa opción, verás todos los activadores actuales, e información sobre ellos, como la última vez que se lanzaron, si hubo errores, o salidas de log si el código emitió alguna.

Este es un ejemplo del panel de activadores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahí sólo hay uno, pero pueden aparecer más, si los hubiera. Cuando pones el puntero sobre cualquiera de los activadores que haya, verás que a la derecha se activan dos opciones, la del lápiz, que es para editarlo, y la de los tres puntos verticales, que te muestra varias opciones como Datos del proyecto, Ejecuciones, Ejecuciones fallidas, etc. Este mismo comportamiento ocurre si revisas los activadores desde el enlace indicado al inicio de la respuesta.

Un activador puede programarse manualmente, o por código. Puede que en tu caso, probando cosas, hayas dejado más de uno activado.

Conviene trastear de vez en cuando por la interfaz gráfica de los programas que usas, esconden cosas muy útiles que a veces no sabemos siquiera que están ahí :-)